# How to get Outlook Appointment from ContextMenu

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I have added a ContextMenuItem to the ContextMenu for Outlook appointments.

[image: The menu item]

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the Appointment object. In the event I get an IRibbonControl, and its Context property should contain the Appointment, but it contains a Selection instead. I can't use the Selection to get to the Appointment as far as I can see.

[image]

This page is where I'm coming from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863278%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Anyone knows of how to get the Appointment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860771(v=office.15).aspx) object contains the AppointmentItem object selected on the picture. For example:

```
                Object selObject = Selection[1];
                if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                        (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                    itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message." +
                        " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ".";
                    mailItem.Display(false);
                }
                else if (selObject is Outlook.ContactItem)
                {
                    Outlook.ContactItem contactItem =
                        (selObject as Outlook.ContactItem);
                    itemMessage = "The item is a contact." +
                        " The full name is " + contactItem.Subject + ".";
                    contactItem.Display(false);
                }
                else if (selObject is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                {
                    Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem =
                        (selObject as Outlook.AppointmentItem);
                    itemMessage = "The item is an appointment." +
                        " The subject is " + apptItem.Subject + ".";
                }
                else if (selObject is Outlook.TaskItem)
                {
                    Outlook.TaskItem taskItem =
                        (selObject as Outlook.TaskItem);
                    itemMessage = "The item is a task. The body is "
                        + taskItem.Body + ".";
                }
                else if (selObject is Outlook.MeetingItem)
                {
                    Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem =
                        (selObject as Outlook.MeetingItem);
                    itemMessage = "The item is a meeting item. " +
                         "The subject is " + meetingItem.Subject + ".";
                }
```

See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Explorer.Selection collection must not be used. See my answer.

Comment: Dmitry, actually I didn't suggest to use the Explorer object. The Context property of the IRibbonControl is used to get a Selection object based on the code shown in the initial post. Why did you think about the Explorer?

Comment: The link in your reply uses Explorer.Selection.

Comment: It just describes the Selection object... Anyway, I think author knows the right way how to get the Selection object.

Answer (score 0):

Do ***not*** use Explorer.Selection in the popup menu event handler - it is possible to select one message and then right click on another message without selecting it. The Explorer.Selection collection will not change, and Explorer.SelectionChange event will not fire.

When you process the event handler, Context parameter will be passed to you. Cast it to the Selection object and use it instead. That collection will be different from the Explorer.Selection object.

Comment: The IRibbonControl.Context property is used in the code to get the Selection object.

Comment: Where? I do not see it in the original question or in your answer.

Comment: Take a look at the SendToGoogle method.

Comment: I am sorry, I am probably being blind - what exactly do you see in SendToGoogle?

Comment: The IRibbonControl.Context property is used to get the Selection object. Am I wrong?

Comment: I see that Control.Context is retrieved. Where do you see Selection?

Comment: At the bottom of the screenshot. Marked with yellow.